# Access IQueryable object member from string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iqueryable

I want to make a function template that changes in only one meaningful way.  I'm currently creating individual ActionResult's to change user settings in my MVC application.  There are a lot of options and I'm trying tired of writing out a new ActionResult method for every single checkbox so I need a little direction on how to access and set values where I do not explicitly set an objects member with dot notation.

Here's an example of a checkbox ActionResult currently:

```
public ActionResult ChangeActivityShowNewProduct(bool value)
{
    var _id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
    var dataContext = new SecurityDataContext();
    var x = from c in dataContext.UserSettings
            where c.UserID == _id
            select c;

    foreach (var setting in x)
    {
        setting.ActivityShowNewProduct = value;
    }

    dataContext.SubmitChanges();

    Session["ActivityShowNewProduct"] = value;

    return Json(Session["ActivityShowNewProduct"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Another example would be very similar but possibly called "ChangeActivityShowNewUser" where the only difference in the underlying code would be in the foreach loop having `setting.ActivityShowNewUser` instead (as well as the session variables but I'm not worried about assigning those).

Is there anyway to set the `setting`'s member with a string?  Perhaps out of a foreach loop?  I'm not very versed with the IQueryable object yet so I'm not too sure where to start looking.  Any reference materials would be much appreciated!

### UPDATE

---

There we go.  It works but it's a bit repetitive, I'm working on that.  Posting for others and/or critique.  Thanks guys.

```
Func<int, bool, Action<UserSetting>, bool> CheckBoxChanger = (i, b, v) =>
{
    var _id = i;

    var dataContext = new SecurityDataContext();
    var x = from c in dataContext.UserSettings
            where c.UserID == _id
            select c;

    foreach (var setting in x)
    {
        v(setting);
    }

    dataContext.SubmitChanges();

    return b;
};

public ActionResult CheckBoxSettingChange(Action<UserSetting> valueSetter, bool result, string SessionName)
{
    Session[SessionName] = CheckBoxChanger(Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]), result, valueSetter);

    return Json(Session[SessionName], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public void DoIt(string name, bool val)
{
    switch (name)
    {
        case "ChangeActivityShowNewProduct":
            CheckBoxSettingChange(setting => setting.ActivityShowNewProduct = val, val, name);
            break;

        // ... etc etc etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Your updated version looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time you're executing the `foreach` loop it's no longer just a query; it has been materialized into a result.

You can just have this method accept a method which takes the item and sets that value.  Then you can just call that method on each item:

```
public ActionResult ChangeActivityShowNewProduct(Action<UserSetting> valueSetter)
{
    //...
    foreach (var setting in x)
        valueSetter(setting);
    //...
}
```

Then to call it you would have something like:

```
ChangeActivityShowNewProduct(setting => setting.ActivityShowNewProduct = false);
```

Comment: That is the answer I would have done, but I got hung up on how to handle `Session["ActivityShowNewProduct"] = value;` at the bottom of the function (which you do not address).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I was under the impression he was planning to just pass in the string value as well.  If it was *really* important to avoid it, then it would be possible, but it would complicate the solution a fair bit to do it.  As for how, one could accept an `Expression` instead and extract the value out of it.